# how to add selected option to a table dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add the selected option in a select list  to a table with delete option for each row created automatically.

So when I click on delete option the entire row should be deleted in the table and that option should be available in the select list again.

I added the select option to the table but it is not displaying as `<td>`, instead it displays as `<option>`.

Comment: Here is the fiddle to my code http://jsfiddle.net/c8q2sggn/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just adjusted the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uLbq87bf/) with the option to delete the added row. Two adjustments - for convenience I add the added option value as data-value attribute to the added row and add the class delete to the `Del` column:

```
var row = $('<tr data-value="' + opt.val() + '"><td>' + opt.val() + 
          '</td><td></td><td class="delete">Del</td></tr>');
```

Then I added the following function to add the option from the deletd row and removing the row:

```
$("#selectDistriList").on("click", ".delete", function () {
    dVal = $(this).closest("tr").data("value");
    $("#distriList").append('<option value="' + dVal + '">' 
       + dVal + '</option>');
   $(this).closest("tr").remove();
});
```

**Update:** For the question in the comment if it's possible to add a link to each option I've just adjusted the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0zm7ggrv/) with some example links.
Following adjustments: I added the attribute `data-link` for each option, e.g.

```
 <option value="A" data-link="http://www.stackoverflow.com">A</option>
```

The row that will be appended to the table is adjusted to have the link as `data-link` attribute on the `<tr>` and sets the link to the value:

```
var row = $('<tr data-value="' + opt.val() + '" data-link="' 
          + opt.data("link") + '"><td><a href="' + opt.data("link") 
          + '" target="_blank">' + opt.val() + '</a></td><td></td>
            <td class="delete">Del</td></tr>');
```

The function that deletes the row on click is adjusted to set the `data-link` value of the deleted row to the option that's appended:

```
$("#selectDistriList").on("click", ".delete", function () {
  dVal = $(this).closest("tr").data("value");
  dLink = $(this).closest("tr").data("link");
  $("#distriList").append('<option value="' + dVal + '" data-link="' 
    + dLink + '">' + dVal + '</option>');
  $(this).closest("tr").remove();
});
```

**Update:** For the question in the comments how to add multiple selected options I've just adjusted the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6f0uetz3/)

Following adjustment for the `add` function:

```
$('#Add').click(function () {

 if ($('#distriList option:selected').val() != null) {
     $('#distriList option:selected').each(function ()
     {
        var tempSelect = $(this).val();
        var inbtn = $('#Include').val();
        var opt = $('#distriList option[value=' + tempSelect + ']').remove();
        var row = $('<tr data-value="' + opt.val() + '" data-link="' + opt.data("link") + '"><td><a href="' + opt.data("link") + '" target="_blank">' + opt.val() + '</a></td><td></td><td class="delete">Del</td></tr>');
        row.appendTo('#selectDistriList');
        $("#distriList").attr('selectedIndex', '-1').find("option:selected").removeAttr("selected");
        $("#selectDistriList").attr('selectedIndex', '-1').find("option:selected").removeAttr("selected");
        $("#selectDistriList").val(tempSelect);
    });      
 }
 else
 {
    alert("Before add please select any position.");
 }
});
```

Instead of adding only `$('#distriList option:selected')` which would only add the first selected option, `.each()` iterates over all selected options and adds them.

For reference: http://api.jquery.com/each/

Comment: It worked great.. Is it possible to give links to A,B,C values in table. Each value will have its unique link.

Comment: @user13 Glad I was able to be of help. I've updated my answer for the adjustment to add links to the values.

Comment: When I select multiple options and click on Add button only 1st option is getting added. How to make all the selected options to be included. Am selecting multiple options by pressing CTRL + select

Answer (score 0):

You're adding `<option>` tag to the table, but it needs `<tr>`:

```
var opt = $('#distriList option:selected').remove();
var row = $('<tr><td>' + opt.val() + '</td><td>Add</td><td>Del</td></tr>');
row.appendTo('#selectDistriList');
```

See updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/c8q2sggn/1/.

Comment: It works well..However, If I click on delete button in that particular row then it should be deleted and should available on select list. How to implement this??

Comment: Is it possible to give links to A,B,C values in table. Each value will have its unique link